# Magento 2 - How to extend customer account creation template

Tags: magento2, template, customer-account

I want to extend the customer account creation template (register.phtml) of the Luma theme. 
I copied the register.phtml to my custom theme directory:

> \app\design\frontend\my\theme\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\

and modified it. After flushing the cache and refreshing the browser I can't see my changes.

What is wrong?

Is it always necessary to copy the template in a custom theme folder or is it also possible to copy it to the view folder of my custom module?

Thanks.

Marco

Comment: `app\design\frontend\vendor\theme_name\Magento_Customer\templates`

Comment: Try deleting the cache manually from var/cache and delete all folders, it might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:** I tried the hints, but they didn't solve the problem. After searching for a while I figured out the following path which is working:

> app/design/frontend/my/theme/Magento_Customer/templates/form

Answer (score 0):

your current path of template file is worng

```
\app\design\frontend\my\theme\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\
```

the correct path  will be

```
\app\design\frontend\my\theme\module-customer\templates\
```

Comment: I changed the path, but there is no effect!

Comment: disabled the cache  then check

Answer (score 0):

**Copy the layout file to your theme.**

Copy the customer account creation layout XML file from below location

```
/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml
```

to your theme that you’re editing

```
/app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_create.xml
```

If the template folder does not exists then create a template folder in the given path

```
/app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml
```

replace the below line of code of layout file (which one is copy from core magneto)

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register" template="form/register.phtml">
```

to

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register" template="Magento_Customer::/form/register.phtml">
```

Copy the html code from below location and paste into register.phtml (which one is created in theme directory)

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form
```